# Align images on the same row with a background

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I want to align my images on the same row and inside my div class for headings, so essentially I want the white background with the round borders that are behind the heading 'Nike' and 'Iconic Nike shoe released in the early 80s' to also be behind both shoe images. I'm using HTML and CSS, there is a div class called  NikeIntro that is used for the white background and both headings - Can anyone help please!

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient( circle, rgb(175, 243, 154) 0%, rgb(142, 215, 248) 100%);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.NikeIntro {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 60px;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: block;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Shoes {
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#mainDiv {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="NikeIntro">
  <h1>
    Nike
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Iconic Nike shoe released in the early 80's
  </h2>
</div>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="divOne" class="Shoes">
    <img src="https://sneakerbardetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Nike-Air-Force-1-Shadow-Pale-Ivory-CI0919-101-Release-Date-4.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="divTwo" class="Shoes">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/shecodesio-production/uploads/files/000/001/250/original/Nike-Air-Force-1-Sage-Pink-Quartz-CW5566-100-Release-Date__1_-removebg-preview.png?1592256128" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the code snippet to see if that is what you need. I am not sure if I understand your requirement. Basically, I use flexbox to align your items.

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient( circle, rgb(175, 243, 154) 0%, rgb(142, 215, 248) 100%);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.NikeIntro {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 60px;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /*padding: 50px 100px;*/
  border-radius: 50px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.Shoes {
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*width: 50%;
  float: left;*/
}

#mainDiv {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

#divOne {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

#divTwo {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="divOne" class="Shoes">
    <img src="https://sneakerbardetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Nike-Air-Force-1-Shadow-Pale-Ivory-CI0919-101-Release-Date-4.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="NikeIntro">
    <h1>
      Nike
    </h1>
    <h2>
      Iconic Nike shoe released in the early 80's
    </h2>
  </div>


  <div id="divTwo" class="Shoes">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/shecodesio-production/uploads/files/000/001/250/original/Nike-Air-Force-1-Sage-Pink-Quartz-CW5566-100-Release-Date__1_-removebg-preview.png?1592256128" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```